# How do I change the font size in the root shell on Knoppix running LXDE?

Tags: terminal, root, appearance, lxde, knoppix

The root shell's font is too small, and I have scoured Google looking for an answer. I can't find the settings for it, or a config file of some sort.

I'm using the latest version of Knoppix with LXDE.

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Did you try the usuals, such as <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>SHIFT</kbd>+<kbd>+</kbd>?

Comment: Yes, they don't work.